Why does TypeScript complain about spread arguments in callback wrappers
I'm trying to wrap a callback function in TypeScript with some additional logic. I have an interface Callbacks that defines several callback signatures. My goal is to create a wrapper function that can log a message and then call the original callback.
Here is the Callbacks interface:
interface Callbacks {
  foo: (a: string, b: string) => void;
  bar: (x: number) => void;
  baz: (z: boolean) => void;
}

type CbType = keyof Callbacks;

I tried to implement the trigger and wrapTrigger functions like this:
function trigger<T extends CbType>(name: T, cb: Callbacks[T]) {
  // do stuff
}

function wrapTrigger<T extends CbType>(name: T, cb: Callbacks[T]) {
  return trigger(name, (...args: Parameters<Callbacks[T]>) => {
    console.log('Triggered!');
    return cb(...args);
  });
}

However, I get the following errors:
enter image description here

Argument of type '(...args: Parameters<Callbacks[T]>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callbacks[T]'
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

To work around this, I modified the trigger function to accept callbacks with rest parameters, and it works:
function triggerSpread<T extends CbType>(name: T, cb: (...args: Parameters<Callbacks[T]>) => ReturnType<Callbacks[T]>) {
  // do other stuff
}

function wrapTriggerSpread<T extends CbType>(name: T, cb: (...args: Parameters<Callbacks[T]>) => ReturnType<Callbacks[T]>) {
  return triggerSpread(name, (...args) => {
    console.log('Triggered!');
    return cb(...args);
  });
}

This approach works without any errors. But I don't like defining all the signatures through the rest parameters.
Why does the first approach fail with type errors, and why does using rest parameters in the second approach resolve these issues?
Playground

Parameters<T> is a conditional type; TS doesn't know what it means, it just evaluates it when T is a specific type. When T is generic (as in Callbacks[K]), it defers evaluation, so TS can't verify that any value is assignable. It lacks the higher order concept that (...args: Parameters<T>) => void should always be assignable to T. The second approach works because the parameter type is identical in both cases, although the idiomatic way to write this looks like this. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz I guess it addresses the q, but the thing is that I'd like it to work without this workaround. Do you agree that from logical point of view it should allow to spread Parameters into original cb arguments? If that's true it means TS compiler ignores the logic in this case. So I'm trying to understand if there's a different way to implement it or it'll be probably fixed in the next versions of TS

I understand that you'd like it to behave differently, but it doesn't, and I explained why. TS isn't a proof solver. Maybe you'd say it "ignores" the logic, in the same way a bird "ignores" a keep-off-the-grass sign. You are expecting too much of the compiler. See ms/TS#47615 and ms/TS#42818. Am I missing anything now or should I write an answer?

Ok, you can write an answer, and please mention these GH issues

@jcalz Thanks for the answer! Regarding your bird remark, I don't quite agree. It's logical the same way that there are no married bachelors, like mathematical logic. There's no universe where (...args: Parameters<Callbacks[T]>) => void is not assignable to Callbacks[T] having Callbacks defined the way it is, namely {[key]: someFunction}.
There were many cases in the past when TS didn't see the obvious logic, but with a new version it would fix that. So I think there's a hope :)

Do you mean that you expect TypeScript to be able to verify the truth of all statements which are logical tautologies? Or just the ones that you have decided are "obvious"? If you don't know what the word "bachelor" means, you probably can't easily conclude that "all bachelors are unmarried" is true. TS doesn't know what Parameters means.

TypeScript is generally unable to abstract facts about specific types to their generic counterparts, especially when conditional types are involved. For any function f of a specific type, TypeScript will be able to see that f is assignable to (...args: Parameters<typeof f>) => void:
function foo(x: string, y: number) { return x.toUpperCase() + y.toFixed() }
const alsoFoo: (...args: Parameters<typeof foo>) => void = foo; // okay

function bar(z: boolean) { return z ? 0 : 1 }
const alsoBar: (...args: Parameters<typeof bar>) => void = bar; // okay

But when f is of generic type F, TypeScript cannot see this:
function oops<F extends (...args: any) => any>(f: F) {
  const alsoF: (...args: Parameters<typeof f>) => void = bar; // error!
}

That's because while you understand the meaning of the Parameters<T> utility type, TypeScript doesn't. It's just a conditional type. When T is generic, TypeScript doesn't even attempt to see through it to some higher-order truth about functions. It just says "I don't know what T is yet so I can't figure out what Parameters<T> is yet either".  It just defers evaluation. So it can't see what values might or might not be assignable to it.
This is a design limitation of TypeScript, as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47615 and microsoft/TypeScript#42818. It's doubtful that any future version of TypeScript will allow this to work automatically.
If you want TypeScript to see some types as being the same, you pretty much need to write them the same way. Your "spread" code, where both mentions of the callback are essentially of type (...args: Parameters<Callbacks[T]>) => void, works this way.

The standard refactoring of this sort of correlation is described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109, where there is a "base" interface relating keys and some underlying data type, and then all your operations are written in terms of that base interface, or in terms of mapped types into that interface, or in terms of generic indexed accesses into those types.
For your example that looks like
interface CallbackParams {
  foo: [a: string, b: string];
  bar: [x: number];
  baz: [z: boolean];
}

type Callback<K extends keyof CallbackParams> =
  { [P in K]: (...args: CallbackParams[P]) => void }[K]

function trigger<K extends keyof CallbackParams>(
  name: K,
  cb: Callback<K>
) {
  // do stuff
}

function wrapTrigger<K extends keyof CallbackParams>(
  name: K,
  cb: Callback<K>
) {
  return trigger(name, (...args) => {
    console.log('Triggered!');
    return cb(...args);
  });
}

which is similar to your "spread" version. (There are situations where it matters that Callback<K> is a distributive object type instead of just (...args: CallbackParams[K]) => void but they are not relevant here. See microsoft/TypeScript#47109 for more details).
Playground link to code
